# SAS Enterprise Guide log line number doesn't make sense

Tags: sas, enterprise-guide

I am getting a warning in the log when running a program but the line number where it says the warning occurs does not make sense. I've copied part of the log below. It says that the operation occurs at line 4229 but there are only 1500 lines in my code and the warning is at line 1895 in the log. Why is it telling me the warning occurs at line 4229 when there are only 1500 lines in my code?

> WARNING: Division by zero, result set to missing value.

count     : number of occurrences is 201
 operation : / at line 4229 column 11
 operands  : _TEM1001, _TEM1002
_TEM1001      1 row     201 cols    (numeric)

_TEM1002      1 row       1 col     (numeric)

```
     0
```

statement : ASSIGN at line 4228 column 245
WARNING: Division by zero, result set to missing value.

count     : number of occurrences is 201
 operation : / at line 4229 column 43
 operands  : _TEM1001, _TEM1003
_TEM1001      1 row     201 cols    (numeric)

_TEM1003      1 row       1 col     (numeric)

```
     0
```

Comment: Are you using any Macros?

Comment: If you clear the log, the log row numbers do not get reset.

Comment: Yes it is within a macro

Comment: This program was the first thing I ran after opening SAS so there shouldn't have been anything else in the log before the program ran.

Comment: If you're running a macro a bunch of times, each time the macro is run will create a new line.  This is not really an answerable question without the actual code.

Answer (score 0):

As stated, the macro is generating SAS code for you, making the number of SAS lines submitted more than the number of lines in your code.

Turn on MPRINT to see the code that is causing the problem.  From your error lines, it looks like you are using IML.  Here is an example:

```
%macro loop_then_error();
%do i=10 %to 0 %by -1;
proc iml;
x = {1 1};
x = (x || x) / &i;
quit;
%end;
%mend;

options nomprint;
%loop_then_error;

options mprint;
%loop_then_error;
```